# Liquibase fails with MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I want to get an example of liquibase, Spring and MongoDB all together. In order to do so, I created a Spring project using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with Spring Data MongoDB as dependency. The project already connects to the database and now I would like to use liquibase. I followed the [instructions from liquibase](https://docs.liquibase.com/install/tutorials/mongodb.html) using the maven approach but if I run the maven command `mvn liquibase:status` I will get the following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot find database driver: com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.<init>()
```

It looks like [this problem has been already reported to liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1160) but if there is a solution it hasn't been posted in the issue.

I tried as well to use the CLI option by adding the jars to the lib folder of the liquibase installation. I got the same error if I run `liquibase status`

[I have created a repo in GitHub to show the problem.](https://github.com/legolaz8451/spring-boot-mongo) Here there is some relevant configuration of the code:

pom.xml

```
<project>
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<properties>
    <liquibase-mongo-ext.version>4.14.0</liquibase-mongo-ext.version>
    <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>4.2.0</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase-mongo-ext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-mongodb</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-mongo-ext.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
                    <version>4.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

liquibase.properties

```
changeLogFile=./mongo/changelog/changelog.sql
url=jdbc:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local
driver=com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
```

How can I get liquibase running with maven? Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**
As Andrey suggested:

- Driver was updated to: `driver=liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoClientDriver`
- Url was updated to:
  `url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local`
- plugin from liquibase was updated with new dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

`mvn liquibase:update` now trhows the following error. Since the other error seems to be unrelated to this one. I'll solve this answer and create a new thread.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.2.0:update (default-cli) on project mongo: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.2.0:update failed: A required class was missing while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.2.0:update: liquibase/configuration/HubConfiguration
```

**EDIT 2:**
As mentioned in the answer, there was a mismatch between the version from Spring and the version of the plugin, which failed to find the class because [HubConfiguration class is now under liquibase.hub.HubConfiguration](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/4.9.1/liquibase/hub/HubConfiguration.html) This set up [could have led to a CastException as well](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1536). So I updated the version `liquibase-maven-plugin` to `4.9.1`

Also the use of the local database is not compatible with validators. The URI was updated to `url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test` in the `liquibase.properties` file.

Now it works like a charm! :D

Comment: could you post your pom and properties file after all work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found following mistakes in your configuration:

1.

```
changeLogFile=./mongo/changelog/changelog.sql
url=jdbc:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local
driver=com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
```

while `liquibase-mongodb` expects something like (no `jdbc` prefix, another driver class):

```
changeLogFile=./mongo/changelog/changelog.sql
url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local
driver=liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoClientDriver
```

2. liquibase version:

```
<liquibase-maven-plugin.version>4.2.0</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
```

- 4.2.0 liquibase version seems to be [incompatible with NoSQL DB extensions](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1536)
- spring boot 2.7.3 uses liquibase 4.9.1 - you need somehow choose the correct liquibase version

Finally I get the following on `liquibase:update`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.14.0:update (default-cli) on
> project mongo:  [ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase: [ERROR]
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Could not execute: Command
> failed with error 72 (InvalidOptions): 'Document validators are not
> allowed on collection local.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK with UUID
> 31bd40b8-3e1c-45c8-9d03-77b91c67a1a9 in the local internal database'
> on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg":
> "Document validators are not allowed on collection
> local.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK with UUID
> 31bd40b8-3e1c-45c8-9d03-77b91c67a1a9 in the local internal database",
> "code": 72, "codeName": "InvalidOptions"}

no idea what does it mean - something related to mongodb and extension I believe

---

UPD.

The root cause of last error is described in [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/):

**Restrictions**

You cannot specify a validator for collections in the admin, local, and config databases.

You cannot specify a validator for system.* collections.

So, url (`jdbc:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local`) should point to another db.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, after your changes I got the same error. Then I added the dependency in the plugin section of liquibase (liquibase-core 4.9.1 as you suggested) and I go forward. I also changed the changelog file to include and got another error. I will open another question if I don't make it work.

Comment: @Edu That is mongodb restriction, please check UPD.

Comment: yes, you're right, and thanks for the feedback again. I changed the database name to `test`. The problem with HubConfiguration was related to a messed versioning as you already mentioned before. I will update the answer